# sumproduct of List or Array using lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to get the sumproduct (values * index) of a List or Array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{
    sumproduct += myList[i] * i;
}
```

Can this be done using a lambda expression?

In general, can I access the *index* of a List or Array in lambda expressions?

Something with syntax similar to:

```
sumproduct = myList.Sum((value, index) => value * index);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sumproduct = myList.Select((i, j) => i*j).Sum();
```

This uses the [second overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) of `Select()` that includes index.